# Android Studio cannot find library project package

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to import this library in android studio

https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

I downloaded it locally then what I did was right click on my project, select `Open Module Settings` selected `Modules` clicked the `+` on the module list and selected `Import Module` and imported the library.

Then I clicked on the `Dependencies` tab and clicked the `+` there and added the module that I just added.

when I try to build my project I get an error saying `package com.edmodo.rangebar does not exist`

what did I miss when importing the library?

Comment: I have tried your link, try to import your project in android studio from ../range-bar-master. this will automatically add lib project to sample project.

Comment: I dont care about the sample project though, I want to implement it into my project

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it but in some other ways.
First I import it in eclipse and then from eclipse export it with gradle project.

Then in android studio, import only the gradle.build file, before importing, make some minor changes in gradle.bulde and in gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties.

in geadle.build change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'

in gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties change distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip to distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip

hopefully, this will help you.